# UTF8 Message formatter in java

Tags: java, text, string-formatting

So I have a Persian text with some parameters to place in.
the sample text is like below:

**نام کاربری {} به مدت {} دقیقه مسدود شده است**
the output text must be in RTL format and have parameters injected into it.
what is the best solution to write this in java?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is text, and thus a language and a language from a region you need to format the String using the static method format() that takes an argument of object type java.util.Locale that takes a special country code and a language code.
That puts a marker on the string with the JVM to remember.
One more obscure point about Locale not mention is another of its settings is "script" meaning human geographical language calligraphy type.
The JVM apart bound to the OS Locale region setting it has can do conversions or explicitly use other locale and charsets, read and write these if they are present configured in the OS.
The Java specifications for these are an international ISO standard, inclusive their registered naming codes.
See the API docs for Locale.
If writing to a file one of the printwriters or stringwriters will convert or tag the data written to file alike using java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder, if writing to a panel or textpane in a GUI, the ISO charset can be set for Locale and text direction by region with proper Locale settings.
Print separate sections (string) each  action of as separate language.
See  RamHttpTools class API docs for info too if you want
some code
http://windsolarhybridaustralia.x10.mx/httpoutputtools-tomcat-java.html